# Customizing rolling_apply function in Python pandas

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, aggregate, data-analysis

### Setup

I have a DataFrame with three columns:

- "Category" contains True and False, and I have done `df.groupby('Category')` to group by these values.
- "Time" contains timestamps (measured in seconds) at which values have been recorded
- "Value" contains the values themselves.

At each time instance, two values are recorded: one has category "True", and the other has category "False".

### Rolling apply question

**Within each category group**, I want to **compute a number and store it in column Result for each time**. Result is **the percentage of values between time `t-60` and `t` that fall between 1 and 3.**

The easiest way to accomplish this is probably to calculate the total number of values in that time interval via `rolling_count`, then execute `rolling_apply` to count only the values from that interval that fall between 1 and 3.

Here is my code so far:

```
groups = df.groupby(['Category'])
for key, grp in groups:
    grp = grp.reindex(grp['Time']) # reindex by time so we can count with rolling windows
    grp['total'] = pd.rolling_count(grp['Value'], window=60) # count number of values in the last 60 seconds
    grp['in_interval'] = ? ## Need to count number of values where 1<v<3 in the last 60 seconds

    grp['Result'] = grp['in_interval'] / grp['total'] # percentage of values between 1 and 3 in the last 60 seconds
```

What is the proper `rolling_apply()` call to find `grp['in_interval']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's work through an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

def setup(regular=True):
    N = 10
    x = np.arange(N)
    a = np.arange(N)
    b = np.arange(N)

    if regular:
        timestamps = np.linspace(0, 120, N)
    else:
        timestamps = np.random.uniform(0, 120, N)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Category': [True]*N + [False]*N,
        'Time': np.hstack((timestamps, timestamps)),
        'Value': np.hstack((a,b))
        })
    return df

df = setup(regular=False)
df.sort(['Category', 'Time'], inplace=True)
```

So the DataFrame, `df`, looks like this:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   Category       Time  Value    Result
12    False   0.013725      2  1.000000
15    False  11.080631      5  0.500000
14    False  17.610707      4  0.333333
16    False  22.351225      6  0.250000
13    False  36.279909      3  0.400000
17    False  41.467287      7  0.333333
18    False  47.612097      8  0.285714
10    False  50.042641      0  0.250000
19    False  64.658008      9  0.125000
11    False  86.438939      1  0.333333
2      True   0.013725      2  1.000000
5      True  11.080631      5  0.500000
4      True  17.610707      4  0.333333
6      True  22.351225      6  0.250000
3      True  36.279909      3  0.400000
7      True  41.467287      7  0.333333
8      True  47.612097      8  0.285714
0      True  50.042641      0  0.250000
9      True  64.658008      9  0.125000
1      True  86.438939      1  0.333333
```

Now, copying @herrfz, let's define

```
def between(a, b):
    def between_percentage(series):
        return float(len(series[(a <= series) & (series < b)])) / float(len(series))
    return between_percentage
```

`between(1,3)` is a function which takes a Series as input and returns the fraction of its elements which lie in the half-open interval `[1,3)`. For example,

```
In [9]: series = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

In [10]: between(1,3)(series)
Out[10]: 0.4
```

Now we are going to take our DataFrame, `df`, and group by `Category`:

```
df.groupby(['Category'])
```

For each group in the groupby object, we will want to apply a function:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby(['Category']).apply(toeach_category)
```

The function, `toeach_category`, will take a (sub)DataFrame as input, and return a DataFrame as output. The entire result will be assigned to a new column of `df` called `Result`.

Now what exactly must `toeach_category` do? If we write `toeach_category` like this:

```
def toeach_category(subf):
    print(subf)
```

then we see each `subf` is a DataFrame such as this one (when `Category` is False):

```
   Category       Time  Value    Result
12    False   0.013725      2  1.000000
15    False  11.080631      5  0.500000
14    False  17.610707      4  0.333333
16    False  22.351225      6  0.250000
13    False  36.279909      3  0.400000
17    False  41.467287      7  0.333333
18    False  47.612097      8  0.285714
10    False  50.042641      0  0.250000
19    False  64.658008      9  0.125000
11    False  86.438939      1  0.333333
```

We want to take the Times column, and *for each time*, apply a function. That's done with `applymap`:

```
def toeach_category(subf):
    result = subf[['Time']].applymap(percentage)
```

The function `percentage` will take a time value as input, and return a value as output. The value will be the fraction of rows with values between 1 and 3. `applymap` is very strict: `percentage` can not take any other arguments.

Given a time `t`, we can select the `Value`s from `subf` whose times are in the half-open interval `(t-60, t]` using the `ix` method:

```
subf.ix[(t-60 < subf['Time']) & (subf['Time'] <= t), 'Value']
```

And so we can find the percentage of those `Values` between 1 and 3 by applying `between(1,3)`:

```
between(1,3)(subf.ix[(t-60 < subf['Time']) & (subf['Time'] <= t), 'Value'])
```

Now remember that we want a function `percentage` which takes `t` as input and returns the above expression as output:

```
def percentage(t):
    return between(1,3)(subf.ix[(t-60 < subf['Time']) & (subf['Time'] <= t), 'Value'])
```

But notice that `percentage` depends on `subf`, and we are not allowed to pass `subf` to `percentage` as an argument (again, because `applymap` is very strict).

So how do we get out of this jam? The solution is to define `percentage` inside `toeach_category`. Python's scoping rules say that a bare name like `subf` is first looked for in the Local scope, then the Enclosing scope, the the Global scope, and lastly in the Builtin scope. When `percentage(t)` is called, and Python encounters `subf`, Python first looks in the Local scope for the value of `subf`. Since `subf` is not a local variable in `percentage`, Python looks for it in the Enclosing scope of the function `toeach_category`. It finds `subf` there. Perfect. That is just what we need.

So now we have our function `toeach_category`:

```
def toeach_category(subf):
    def percentage(t):
        return between(1, 3)(
            subf.ix[(t - 60 < subf['Time']) & (subf['Time'] <= t), 'Value'])
    result = subf[['Time']].applymap(percentage)
    return result
```

---

Putting it all together,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)


def setup(regular=True):
    N = 10
    x = np.arange(N)
    a = np.arange(N)
    b = np.arange(N)

    if regular:
        timestamps = np.linspace(0, 120, N)
    else:
        timestamps = np.random.uniform(0, 120, N)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Category': [True] * N + [False] * N,
        'Time': np.hstack((timestamps, timestamps)),
        'Value': np.hstack((a, b))
    })
    return df


def between(a, b):
    def between_percentage(series):
        return float(len(series[(a <= series) & (series < b)])) / float(len(series))
    return between_percentage


def toeach_category(subf):
    def percentage(t):
        return between(1, 3)(
            subf.ix[(t - 60 < subf['Time']) & (subf['Time'] <= t), 'Value'])
    result = subf[['Time']].applymap(percentage)
    return result


df = setup(regular=False)
df.sort(['Category', 'Time'], inplace=True)
df['Result'] = df.groupby(['Category']).apply(toeach_category)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   Category       Time  Value    Result
12    False   0.013725      2  1.000000
15    False  11.080631      5  0.500000
14    False  17.610707      4  0.333333
16    False  22.351225      6  0.250000
13    False  36.279909      3  0.200000
17    False  41.467287      7  0.166667
18    False  47.612097      8  0.142857
10    False  50.042641      0  0.125000
19    False  64.658008      9  0.000000
11    False  86.438939      1  0.166667
2      True   0.013725      2  1.000000
5      True  11.080631      5  0.500000
4      True  17.610707      4  0.333333
6      True  22.351225      6  0.250000
3      True  36.279909      3  0.200000
7      True  41.467287      7  0.166667
8      True  47.612097      8  0.142857
0      True  50.042641      0  0.125000
9      True  64.658008      9  0.000000
1      True  86.438939      1  0.166667
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting and detailed solution.  But why not use apply_rolling as the original question asks? surely it can be used? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: @Carl: `pd.rolling_apply` requires a fixed (integer) window size. In this problem, the window size changes *with each row*, since the window depends on the value in the `Time` column.

Comment: Thanks unutbu, much appreciated.  In the case of fixed window size, how would one use it?

Comment: That question is rather broad.  Please open a new question that spells out the details, or google "pandas pd.rolling_apply site: stackoverflow.com" to find lots of examples.

Comment: There is also an example [in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, you could probably skip `rolling count` if you use it only for the sake of computing the percentage. `rolling_apply` takes as an argument a function that performs aggregation, i.e. a function that takes an array as input and returns a number as an output.

Having this in mind, let's first define a function:

```
def between_1_3_perc(x):
    # pandas Series is basically a numpy array, we can do boolean indexing
    return float(len(x[(x > 1) & (x < 3)])) / float(len(x))
```

Then use the function name as an argument of `rolling_apply` in the for-loop:

```
grp['Result'] = pd.rolling_apply(grp['Value'], 60, between_1_3_perc)
```