# Plotting line(color, attribue defined) graph using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to plot multi-line with different attribute(color, line-type, etc) with pandas grouby data set. My code plots all blue line of multiple source. 
How to apply line attribute at each group?

My code is bleow.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(r'E:\SAT_DATA.xlsx')
glider_data = xls_file.parse('Yosup (4)', parse_dates=[0])
each_glider = glider_data.groupby('Vehicle') 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1); 
glider_data.groupby("Vehicle").plot(x="TimeStamp", y="Temperature(degC)", ax=ax)
plt.legend(glider_data['Vehicle'], loc='best')
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Temp")
plt.show()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting results of Pandas GroupBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465645/plotting-results-of-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop over the groups from `groupby`. Something like:

```
for i,group in glider_data.groupby('Vehicle'):
    group.plot(x='TimeStamp', y='Temperature(degC)', ax=ax, label=i)
```

Comment: Thank you tom, But your suggestion bring same result without label option. label option generated parsing error.